# Cannot query to Titan through Java

Tags: java, titan

I am inserting data into Titan as

```
try{
    //Create a vertex
    Vertex ver1 = tx1.addVertexWithLabel("user");
    ver1.setProperty("PK",entityPK);
    ver1.setProperty("EntitySet",entitySet);
    for (Entry<String, ByteIterator> entry : values.entrySet()){
        //add properties
        ver1.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}
```

And then trying to query

```
Iterable it = graph.query().has("userid",Compare.EQUAL,"1").vertices(); 
Vertex v = (Vertex) it.iterator().next();
System.out.println(v.getProperty("userid"));
```

It throws an exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.next(AbstractIterator.java:154)
```

When I query through gremlin, it shows the data. Why does it throws an exception?